# Rename Files in SharePoint Site Documents

Tags: python

I have an excel file that have the old ifle name, and the new file name.
I want to create a Python script that iterate over the old fiel name into the excel file and connect to Share Point Site, to change the name of files into Documents folders and sub folders.
But i have this error:
`ctx.execute_query()`

```
File "C:\Users\has\anaconda3\envs\knime_python10\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_runtime_context.py", line 141, in execute_query
    self.get_pending_request().execute_query()
  File "C:\Users\has\anaconda3\envs\knime_python10\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_request.py", line 70, in execute_query 
    raise ClientRequestException(*e.args, response=e.response)
office365.runtime.client_request_exception.ClientRequestException: ('-2147024809, System.ArgumentException', 'serverRelativeUrl\r\nParameter name: Specified value is not supported for the serverRelativeUrl parameter.', "400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_api/Web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl
```

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
import pandas as pd
import os

sharepoint_url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName"
library_name = "DataToChange"
local_excel_file_path = r"localExcelFilePath.xlsx"

def load_excel_data(excel_path):
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_path)
    return df

def connect_to_sharepoint(sharepoint_url):
    ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(sharepoint_url)
    ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user("username", "password")
    ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_url, ctx_auth)
    return ctx

# Maybe if anyone make it rename directly withut copy? (because i have a very large size files)
def copy_and_rename_files(ctx, excel_data):
    for index, row in excel_data.iterrows():
        file_name = row['File Name']
        new_file_name = row['NewFileName']
        
        # Construct the correct file URL
        file_url = f"{sharepoint_url}/Shared%20Documents/{library_name}/{file_name}"
        
        file = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_url(file_url)
        ctx.load(file)
        ctx.execute_query()

        # Rename the file in SharePoint
        file_name_without_extension, file_extension = os.path.splitext(new_file_name)
        file_name_without_extension = file_name_without_extension[:128] 
        file_name = f"{file_name_without_extension}{file_extension}"

        file.check_out()
        file.properties['Name'] = file_name
        file.check_in('File renamed via script', 2) 
        ctx.execute_query()
        print(f"Renamed file: {file.properties['Name']}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    excel_data = load_excel_data(local_excel_file_path)
    ctx = connect_to_sharepoint(sharepoint_url)
    copy_and_rename_files(ctx, excel_data)
```

Comment: If your filenames have special characters or spaces in them, the URL will be wrong.  You should probably use `urllib.parse.quote_plus` to do the quoting.  You'll need to change the `%20` back to a space to allow the quoting to work.